# How to reload js module after changing the HTML programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm new to `AngularJS` and I'm working on [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/19/) which is using `AngularJS` to making a slider `<dive> tag`

I want to add another slider to HTML after clicking a button.

This is how I changed the `HTML` part

```
    <article ng-app="angularSlideables">
        <h1 slide-toggle="#derp" >Click here for Hipster Ipsum.</h1>
        <div id="derp" class="slideable">
            <p>Bespoke aesthetic Bushwick craft beer. Qui aesthetic butcher, cardigan ex scenester Neutra American Apparel mumblecore.</p>
        </div>
        <div id="slideholder"></div>
        <button id="goDiv" onclick="goAdd();">Add slider Slider</button>
    </article>
```

And my `Javasciprt` code now looks like this

```
angular.module('angularSlideables', [])
.directive('slideable', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'C',
        compile: function (element, attr) {
            // wrap tag
            var contents = element.html();
            element.html('<div class="slideable_content" style="margin:0 !important; padding:0 !important" >' + contents + '</div>');

            return function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                // default properties
                attrs.duration = (!attrs.duration) ? '1s' : attrs.duration;
                attrs.easing = (!attrs.easing) ? 'ease-in-out' : attrs.easing;
                element.css({
                    'overflow': 'hidden',
                    'height': '0px',
                    'transitionProperty': 'height',
                    'transitionDuration': attrs.duration,
                    'transitionTimingFunction': attrs.easing
                });
            };
        }
    };
})
.directive('slideToggle', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            var target = document.querySelector(attrs.slideToggle);
            attrs.expanded = false;
            element.bind('click', function() {
                var content = target.querySelector('.slideable_content');
                if(!attrs.expanded) {
                    content.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0)';
                    var y = content.clientHeight;
                    content.style.border = 0;
                    target.style.height = y + 'px';
                } else {
                    target.style.height = '0px';
                }
                attrs.expanded = !attrs.expanded;
            });
        }
    }
});


function goAdd() {
 var ht="<h1 slide-toggle='#derpp'>Another Slider</h1><div id='derpp' class='slideable'><p>hi my name is Alex</p></div>";
 document.getElementById('slideholder').innerHTML=ht;
}
```

Although I'm making the exact code, my slider doesn't work. I think its because the module doesn't get to reload after I add some more HTML codes. So my question is how to reload the `javascript` module after I clicked the button?

I'm going to use this code in my `Cordova` project for an android app using `ionic`, if it makes any difference.

Thank you

Comment: why are yoy manually adding html to an angular application ? You should use a ng-if on the element you wanna add instead. This is the angular way.

Comment: Angular uses scope/controllers/directives to manage its events and elements, and the original element is bound via the class `slideable`. if you use normal JS to dump markup into a page, Angular doesn't know about it as it has already parsed the page. You should use Angular to add this element to the page, in turn adding it to the scope, giving angular control.

Comment: In order to make it work with your current approach is to use $compile on the custom html, although I'd advise against it and found a different way, most likely one of the suggested by the guys before me

Comment: @PierreGayvallet Can you tell me how to do that plz?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using Angular 1.1.1 in the fiddle?

Comment: Here's how animations work in Angular - note that I'm using Angular 1.2.1, as the way we work with animations changed for 1.2+: http://jsfiddle.net/3sVz8/401/

Comment: @ShawnErquhart The sample was in 1.1.1 version. There's no reason.And your example is not actually a slide.Plus it's not working anyways.

Comment: What I'm demonstrating in the fiddle is how to use animations in Angular, which you didn't quite seem to understand.

Comment: @ShawnErquhart Don't you have any idea how do i do what I'm trying to do? I tried to do it in your example, but i can't figure it out. Guess I'm really bad in AngularJS!